# Textbox content overflowing out of the screen on Safari but works perfectly on Chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, safari

[image: Chrome Screenshot on the Mac]

[image: Safari Screenshot on the Mac]

The Textbox code seems to break on Safari, Note that both Chrome and Safari Screenshots have been taken from the same system hence the same resolution.

[image: CSS Classes Applied to the Textbox]
[image: HTML Code of the Textbox]

It seems that the Word Wrap is not working on Safari, How do I avoid the content within the box from overflowing?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: What happens if you change from monospace to a normal font?

Comment: try this: word-warp:word-break;

Comment: word-wrap: word-break

Comment: Are you actually giving it any separate words to break on, or only spans? Also, there must be some other CSS around to center that text in the Chrome case so please add anything like that that might be relevant to your code (which must be included in your question, not as an image).